# Loading PrimeNG calendar (date picker) with empty date

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, primeng

I am using [PrimeNG calendar component](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar). Initially I want to render the date input control without any date value and just a placeholder (mm-dd-yy), also as I need date value as a string so I am specifying dataType='string'

JS:

```
private datePickerValue = '';
```

HTML

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="datePickerValue" dateFormat="mm-dd-yy" placeholder="mm-dd-yy" dataType="string"></p-calendar>
```

Problem here is, if my model value (datePickerValue ) is empty string, then the datepicker simply doesn't render.
Now if I initialize model with some string date like:
*private datePickerValue = '01-01-2017';* then the datepicker control will render but it will also render the given date (01-01-2017).

How to render datepicker control without any default date?

Comment: Look at this plunker, it seems to work for me. Can you see if you are doing something very different? https://plnkr.co/edit/prr5qrNrfTYMmWPikpTn?p=preview

Comment: ok not initializing the model value worked i.e. I removed this line: *private datePickerValue = '';* You can put your comment as an answer.

Comment: your question is **NOT** PrimeFaces related. Read what PrimeFaces is. Remember this and please correct all other posts by others that wrongly use the PrimeFaces tag

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, however in our case the datatype is `Date` and using Reactive Forms.

The issue is that if the date is initialized with `new Date()` p-calendar will show a date.  The solution was to set the null/empty date to ''.

```
birthdate: (data.birthdate==null ? '': new Date(data.birthdate))
```